# ORA-00001: unique constraint violated error in oracle jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have this 2 jdbc statement (Oracle 10g with isolation level read committed)

```
delete from emp where emp_id = 1;
insert into emp (emp_id,address,.....) value (1,'newyork',.....);
```

emp_id,address is the primary key

Unfortunately in a multithreaded environment I get ORA-00001: unique constraint  violated while inserting the record.

When I run in a single thread I don't see any issue.

After investigation I found that

- first session deletes and then inserts a record but is not  yet committed.
- second session deletes it
- first session now commits it
- second session now tries to insert it and throws the error .

Let me know if I am missing anything.

How to solve this problem in oracle.I don't like the solution of single threaded ,I also don't like the solution of retry.

Any clean solution?

Comment: Hi Could you please give us more information, how your 2 sessions get the same emp_id to be inserted in the database, you need to identify why more than 1 session are getting the same id.

Comment: emp id and emp address is the key (see the correction in my post)

In here the code first deletes all the record with emp id 1 and then inserts one or more record for the different address

Comment: Hi ,  Do you always get this error or sometimes ?  You have couple of options - 1) It looks like when you are DELETING and COMMITING  the records , at that time some other thread/process is entering the data with the same Unique keys, either you can IGNORE that error and write an error handler procedure to capture those rows. 2) Use MERGE statement which will UPdate or Insert rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled AUTOCOMMIT in your program, then check whether the row exists or not before inserting it to prevent ORA-00001. Here's the PL/SQL block.

```
declare
  v_rows_count number;
begin
  select count(*) into v_rows_count from emp where emp_id = 1;
  if v_rows_count = 0 then
    -- Insert the row
  else
    -- Do not insert the row
  end if;
end;
/
```

Don't forget to commit the change later.

Comment: it will not help..

1) first thread inserts a record  with emp id 1 and address and new york,but does not commit

2) second thread checks the record does not exist 

3) first thread commits

4) second thread now goes and executes insert ...and it fails because the first thread has already inserted the same record

Comment: Do you know about autocommit? You can enable autocommit in your program, then the commit will be done right after any DML without any wait. There's no chance to see step 3.

Comment: I cannot enable auto commit !
Wouldnt that be dangerous for a huge transaction such as ours .It can leave a transaction in a corrupt state.

auto commit is not an option for me